# getting OS Full name throws error

Tags: vb.net, windows, win32-process

I am trying to get OS full name using vb.net

`Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.Info.OSFullName)`

It works fine in most of the machines. One of the Windows 7 machine throws

`Unhandled Exception: system.management.managementexception invalid class`

google search does not help. Does anyone know what is causing this error?

---

It is set to Any CPU. So, It is not duplicate of [ManagementException - Invalid Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804761/managementexception-invalid-class)

---

More Info:

I think below issue is causing the error. still checking how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: What target platform is it compiled against? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804761/managementexception-invalid-class

Comment: @Caramiriel, it is not duplicate. Thanks for sharing that info.

Comment: Could this be that on one machine it runs as very limited user and has no access to this?